Understanding of ISO7816-4 INS 87 GENERAL Authentication in PIV Applet
I'm working on a project involving smart card communication, specifically with PIV (Personal Identity Verification) applets, and I'm having trouble understanding the use of the INS 87 (General Authentication) command as specified in ISO7816-4.
I have specific APDU sequence that I not able to decode specifically data field part
How data field is constructed and what is the response APDU means?
Here is what I know
INS - 87 - GENERAL Authentication
P1 - 03 - Algorithum
P2 - 9B - Slot
TAG:
------------------------------
7C - 80 - Witness (I don't know what exactly Witness means)
# Tag 80 Demonstration of knowledge of a fact without revealingthe fact. An empty witness is a request for a witness.

7C - 81 - Challenge (I don't know what exactly Challenge means, I know it is something related to authenticate user but don't know in details)
7C - 82 - Response
APDU sequence
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
==> Transmitted APDU 1
00 87 03 9B 04 7C 02 80 00
==> Response APDU
7C 0A 80 08 35 34 03 6D 14 98 63 F3 90 00
---------------
==> Transmitted APDU 2
00 87 03 9B 16 7C 14 80 08 1F DE 85 70 42 9D 2F CE 81 08 59 8D 59 47 DC D3 94 15
==> Response APDU
7C 0A 82 08 41 88 14 09 EB 08 09 A5 90 00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

It will be more then appriciated if anyone can provide detail explenations or any details references. Thank you!
I have tryed to get information related the same but got not success. It seems there is not much information/details related to INS 87 datafield.
Already Referring Documents:

ISO+IEC 7816-3-2006
ISO_IEC_7816-4_2020
NIST.SP.800-78-4


A partial answer:

General Authenticate is specified in ISO 7816-4 as a multi-step authentication command. End of useful information.
Especially the command data field is just known to contain authentication-related data
So you have to research in the application specification (in this case apparently PIV).

A witness is some kind of random number, e. g. in Rabin-Miller tests, I don't know, whether PIV can provide a more specific definition.
A challenge is a random number, whose main purpose is to prevent replay attacks - you get a different one (e.g. from the card in External Authenticate context) at the next attempt.
So it seems, that after having requested a witness (response to APDU1) you combine its value and the challenge (the host side seems to provide here) with the referenced key/algorithm.
So check PIV specification for more details, attempting to guess something here will take ages of experimentation.
